# Is it dangerous if cat eats food meant for bearded dragon?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, bearded-dragon

I had my bearded dragon out of his enclosure and my cat likes to crawl in there if I leave the door open. Last time she got in there when I had the dragon out, she chowed down on some of his food. I had to pry her away from it because she was *that* into it. (She's well fed, but not overweight, no health issues.)

My question is, would it harm anything if I just let her have the rest of it? My beardie isn't into this particular food anymore. It's this: [Fluker's Buffet Blend For Juvenile Bearded Dragons](https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/product/flukers-buffet-blend-food-for-juvenile-bearded-dragons)

*Sidenote: Don't worry, I don't leave them together unattended!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of ingredients is quite long and sciency, so please take this advice with a grain of salt.

I broke down the ingredients into categories:

### Protein

> Freeze Dried Mealworms, Freeze Dried Crickets, Chicken Meal, Fish Meal, Potato Protein, Fructose

Not a typical food for cats, but I guess it won't cause any damage.

### Carbohydrates

> Corn, Potato Starch, Corn Gluten Meal, Soybean Meal,

I wouldn't recommend this much starch in cat food, but in a snack it's ok.

### Fat

> Poultry Fat, Soybean Oil, Fish Oil, Coconut Oil,

All are safe for cats and sound tasty for a cat.

### Veggies

> Tomato Pomace

This one is tricky. Fully ripe tomatoes are safe for cats, but green tomatoes contain proteins that are poisonous for cats. You never know if all tomatoes processed for this product where ripe.

### Other stuff

> Calcium Carbonate, L-Lysine, Dl-Methionine, Salt, Spirulina Algae, Canthaxanthin, Lactobacillus Acidophilus Fermentation Product Dehydrated, Streptococcus Faecium Fermentation Product Dehydrated, Dried Bacillus Subtilis Fermentation Extract, Saccharomyces Cerevisiae Fermentation Product Dehydrated, Dicalcium Phosphate, Choline Chloride, Natural And Artificial Flavors, Vitamin E Supplement, Calcium L-Ascorbyl-2-Monophosphate (Stabilized Vitamin C), Ferrous Sulfate, D-Biotin, Yucca Schidigera Extract, Zinc Oxide, Manganous Oxide, Niacinamide, Vitamin B<sub>12</sub> Supplement, Mixed Tocopherols, Rosemary Extract, Copper Sulfate, Calcium Iodate, Vitamin A Acetate, Beta Carotene, Calcium Pantothenate, Sodium Selenite, Folic Acid, Riboflavin, Pyridoxine Hydrochloride, Thiamine Mononitrate, natural and artificial colors, menadione dimethylpyrimidinol bisulfite (source of vitamin K<sub>3</sub>), vitamin D<sub>3</sub> supplement, cobalt sulfate

Many of those are minerals and vitamins, but I have no idea what half of that list actually means.

Riboflavin and tocopherols are common ingredients in cat and dog food. Rosemary extract for example is known to cause seizures in cats and dogs, but as always, the dose makes the poison. Copper sulfate is poisonous for cats as well, but is nonetheless found in cat foods in low concentrations.

**I won't recommend feeding this to your cat** on a regular basis or in bigger amounts. Maybe half a teaspoon once in a while as a treat won't do any damage, but not more than that. *Please keep in mind that I didn't check every single ingredient for its suitability for cats and I don't take any responsibility for the health and safety of your cat.*

Comment: On the ingredients list the half you don't know what means are vitamins, provitamins, amino acids and probiotics (food for bacteria in gut flora); some vitamins are explicitly named, like vitamin B12, others are named using their chemical name, like pyridoxine hydrochloride which is hydrochloride of vitamin B6, or thiamine mononitrate which is mononitrate of vitamin B1; one concern not mentioned could be that there is no taurine mentioned on the list and taurine is an essential amino acid for cats and required to be in large amounts in their diet or else many serious disorders could result.